# Sort descending based on part of a title in Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm having an issue how to sort a title in Wordpress. If I just know how I would solve this in MySQL it would be great. (If someone has an answer specific for wordpress that would be a lot easier for me though)

I have a database where the title (one field in the database-table) is called post_title. The title stores name AND year with a space between

eg.

```
Sweden 2017
Sweden 2016
Norway 2018
Norway 2019
```

I want to sort above like this: (descending by year and ascending by name)

```
Norway 2019
Norway 2018
Sweden 2017
Sweden 2016
```

**UPDATE:**
I've tried with Wordpress-builtin sorting with WP_Query:

```
$module_args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'project',        
                'include_children' => false,   
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'no_found_rows' => true          //No pagination needed
            );

//Do the filtering and retrieve all projects with current service
$projects = get_posts( $module_args );
```

but then I get this result:

```
Yacht 2011
Vasastan 2008
Ulrikagatan 2008
Thailand 2010 (?)
Strandvägen 2007
```

**but it should be:**

```
Yacht 2011
Thailand 2010
Ulrikagatan 2008
Vasastan 2008
Strandvägen 2007
```

Comment: is your table name is wp_posts?

Comment: yes it's wp_posts

Comment: Please find the answer below in few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your input! It was of good help when coming up with a solution.

**This is my solution:**

```
$newsort_projects = array();
foreach ( $projects as $key_item=>$arr_item)
{
    $title = $arr_item->post_title;
    $year_title = substr($title,-4,4);

    $newsort_projects[] = array( 
        'ID' => $arr_item->ID,
        'year'=>$year_title
    );

    }            
    usort($newsort_projects, array($this, 'sort_by_year'));

    $newarr_projects = array();
    foreach ( $newsort_projects as $key_item=>$arr_item )
    {
        foreach($projects as $pkey => $p)
        {
            if ($arr_item['ID'] == $p->ID) {
                $key_to_add = $pkey;
                break;
             }
         }                
         $newarr_projects[] = $projects[$key_to_add];
    }
```

and then I had a function in the class that sorts the mutlidimensional array by key year:

```
private function sort_by_year($a, $b) {
       return $b['year']-$a['year'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following code to get what exactly you need :

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I've tried this. But I see now  that the issue might be that I'm using "special characters" like å,ä,ö in my database (didn't reflect on this before).

Comment: I cant understand your last comment, can you please elaborate it.

Comment: I looked into it, but the basic problem is that the result is quite correct as they are sorting the title which is a string and the year is also a part of that string. So its doing correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with PHP:

```
$titles = [
  'Sweden 2017',
  'Sweden 2016',
  'Norway 2018',
  'Norway 2019',
];

usort($titles, function($a, $b) {
  $asplit = preg_split('/\s/', $a);
  $bsplit = preg_split('/\s/', $b);

  $strcmp = strcmp($asplit[0], $bsplit[0]);

  if ( $strcmp ) {
    return $strcmp;
  }
  else {
    return $bsplit[1] - $asplit[1];
  }
});

// print_r($titles) yields:
//
// Array
// (
//     [0] => Norway 2019
//     [1] => Norway 2018
//     [2] => Sweden 2017
//     [3] => Sweden 2016
// )
```

Edit: fixed typos, now it works

Answer (score 1):

First you need to split values of string and number and then convert that number in string format to intger then do order by as you like.

```
select * from table_name order by
cast(substring(post_title,-4), INTEGER) desc,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_title,' ',1) asc
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql

You could use  a conversion in int for the last four char   and after this for title

```
Order by  CONVERT(right(post_title, 4),UNSIGNED INTEGER) , post_title
```